# PHP String without quotes?

Tags: php

I have an old php codes with strings without quotes like one this `$supplier[id]`, as you are see the id without quotes and is not a variable. There are no `error_reporting(0)` so what there was no stopping it to work?

Comment: Show the code mate, otherwise it's a guessing game.

Comment: The `php` compiler assumes that the `$supplier[id]` is `$supplier['id']`

Comment: This is going to stay valid. However, there'll still be Notices generated. The default error handler will not show them with error_reporting disabled, but the logging handler might pump them out.

Comment: http://wdd.co.il/catalog.php.txt
I have bundle oh these...

Comment: See also: [Using arrays keys without quotes, how to fix it on big project?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27817174)